# Format count query parameters with BookshelfJS

Tags: javascript, orm, bookshelf.js

I'm just getting up to speed with BookshelfJS, so I'm probably missing something, but I'm wondering how to get query parameters to be formatted correctly for doing a count. For example, if I want my JS objects to use camelCase, and the database rows to use snake_case, I know I can use the `format()` and `parse()` functions on the model like so: http://bookshelfjs.org/#parse-and-format

But how do I get query parameters for a count to be converted from camelCase to snake_case before they're run as queries on the DB?

Example:

```
const Book = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'books',
    parse: function(response) {
        return _.mapKeys(response, function(value, key) {
            return _.camelCase(key);
        });
    },
    format: function(attributes) {
        return _.mapKeys(attributes, function(value, key) {
            return _.snakeCase(key);
        });
    }
});
```

Now let's say the `books` database table has `author_name` as a column, but, if this is being used in an API, we want users to query on the `authorName` parameter.

Doing this converts the query parameters just fine:

```
Book.forge({authorName: 'Clark'}).fetch()
```

And it queries the DB on `author_name` instead of `authorName`. But the analogous:

```
Book.forge({authorName: 'Clark'}).count()
```

doesn't work as expected, because it's not converting `authorName` to `author_name` before querying. How do I get bookshelf to use the `format()` function I wrote to do this?